# What's the antecedent of 'them' - '... to let them have their proverbial consequences'?

Tags: meaning-in-context, legalese

[Source:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibson_v_Manchester_City_Council#House_of_Lords) *Gibson v Manchester City Council* [1979], judgement of Lord Diplock

> I therefore feel compelled to allow the appeal. One can sympathise with Mr Gibson's disappointment on finding that his expectations [,] that he would be able to buy his council house at 20 per cent below its market value in the autumn of 1970 [,] cannot be realised. Whether one thinks this makes it a hard case perhaps depends upon the political views that one holds about council housing policy. But **hard cases** offer a strong temptation to let **them** have their proverbial consequences. It is a temptation that the judicial mind must be vigilant to resist.

I first thought that **them** = ***hard cases*** but this is wrong because the disapproving connotation of 'temptation' which (the next sentence says) 'must be vigilant to resist'.

**Update Dec 17 2014:** Thanks. Since I didn't realise that this was a proverb, please clarify 'their proverbial consequences'? Does it mean 'bad law', as mentioned by the users below?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_cases_make_bad_law

Answer (score 2):

The proverb is "***Hard cases make bad law.***"

Thus, "them" refers to the "hard cases".

The proverb has the form:

> <Causes> make <consequences>.

Thus, the "proverbial consequences" are "bad law".

Comment: Thanks. Would you please help with my update in my OP, in view of your answer?

Comment: Will you please to respond in your answer, and not as a comment?